# How to configure PhpStorm or WebStorm or IntelliJ IDEA to group .jsx with related files?

Tags: intellij-idea, coffeescript, phpstorm, reactjs, webstorm

Now .jsx to handle gulp and the output is:

```
-main.jsx
-main.jx
-main.map
```

How to configure PspStorm or WebStorm or IntelliJ IDEA that would be displayed .jsx like CoffeeScript?

```
-main.coffee
--main.js
--main.map
```

Comment: Such nesting is done by File Watcher. So .. configure your file watcher in a similar fashion ("Output paths to refresh" field -- that's where files that should be grouped are described)

Comment: @LazyOne: Maybe, but need a interpreter .jsx

Comment: and how do you interpret .jsx currently? using Gulp task? Configure Gulp as a file watcher then. Grouping can only be established when running file watchers, there is no other way to create such 'nesting' in WebStorm